# IIS Returns "0" Instead of my Html View (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, ssms

I am trying to display data from an SSMS table within a table on my html page, but when I run my program via IIS, it returns "0" on the page but does not crash. I am attempting to display the data via ADO.NET Entity Data Model to display `LoyaltyID` column from table `tLoyalty`. I would like the page to display the table with the `LoyaltyID` in each table row. Any help is much appreciated.

HTML table within view:

```
<div>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Loyalty ID</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                
                @foreach (var query in Model)
                {
                <td>
                    loyaltyinfo.tLoyalty
                </td>                     
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Model class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class tLoyalty
{
    public int LoyaltyID { get; set; }
    public string LoyaltyNumber { get; set; }
    public int StoreID { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DateOfIssue { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> LoyaltyStatusID { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
using Web3.Controllers;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography.Xml;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Web3.Models;

namespace Web3.Controllers
{
    public class LoyaltyController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult LoyaltyInfo()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult LoyaltyQuery()
        {
            var context = new tLoyalty();
            var loyaltyInfo = context.LoyaltyID.ToString();
            return Content(loyaltyInfo);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Firstly, you need to reference your data with `query` since you are iterating over your `Model`. Secondly, you are missing `@` when you are rendering your data in your `<td>`": `<td>@query.tLoyalty</td>`

Answer (score 0):

From this example, you're newing up the tLoyalty class but not setting LoyaltyID to anything. An int will default to 0 as its value; hence the 0 you see on the page. There are probably other missing pieces to this, like connecting a Context to the actual database and how your views are rigged up.